# How to do authentication for android app with GraphQL, Node.js, prisma

Tags: node.js, authentication, graphql, apollo, prisma

I'm wondering whats the best practice for my tech stack: Kotlin android, Apollo GraphQL Client and Server and Prisma ORM to do authentication.
I want a Google Login, Facebook Login and E-Mail Login.

Here is how I would do it but I'm not sure of its correct:
Send Google and Facebook Token via GraphQL Mutation to my backend, authenticate the token, put the data from the token with prisma into my MySQL database with additional Information like posts etc.

Would be glad to hear from someeone experienced on what to look into and how it should work in theory. Seems like there are so many ways on how to do it and its hard to find an implementation with my specific tech stack. I'm overwhelmed and dont know where to start.

Comment: You don't want to use a hosted solution like Auth0,Supabase auth or Firebase auth to implement the authentication system? Do you wish to self implement the whole authentication flow?